# When and where should I add a view to a UITableView's footer?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

I am populating a UITableViewController's UITableView through code only. At the bottom of the table I wish to position a button that scrolls into view as the user scrolls to the bottom of the table.

When in the UITableViewController life cycle should I populate the table footer with a button? viewDidLoad?

p.s. I wish to avoid using section footers in the UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, viewDidLoad is the correct place. It's not a stone-set rule though - I have change footer view in many different situations, such as after rotation in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Note that the view will be repositioned to location immediately below the last row, so if you want to provide a margin or centering for your button I suggest adding a plan UIVIew as footer, and then add your button(s) into that UIView.

Comment: Thank you for that confirmation. Is the height of the UITableView known at UITableViewController viewDidLoad? I ask because in one case I need to position the button at the bottom of the screen when the table takes up less than the whole vertical space of the screen.

Comment: It's not known until tableView queries dataSource for the # of rows & size of each row.

I have done exactly what you describe and it's a lot of work - more than I can describe in a comment. In short, create a separate method refreshFooter and invoke it each time height of the table MIGHT have changed - when you call reloadData, when device rotates etc.

To compute the height of the table I suggest subtracting height of existing footer from self.tableView.contentSize.height. In order to change the footer height you need to remove and add it back, you cant just change the footer frame.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put it in `viewDidLoad`. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/HeaderFooter/index.html) is some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the tableFooterView property of a UITableView to your button.